# REALLY simple functions with tuples (python)

Tags: python, function, tuples

I know this is really easy but I can't understand how to code at all. So I need to create two functions (if you can only help me with one that's fine):

Function a which receives a positive integer and transforms it into a tuple, like this:

```
>>>a(34500)
(3, 4, 5, 0, 0)
>>>a(3.5)
ValueError: a: error
```

And function b which receives a tuple and transforms it into an integer, like this:

```
>>>b((3, 4, 0, 0, 4))
34004
>>>b((2, ’a’, 5))
ValueError: b: error
```

I haven't learned much yet, only functions, while and for cycles, tuples, raise and isinstance(for the error message?), and probably some other things. I've tried looking for answers but they all used things I haven't learned.

Comment: Convert to string and reconvert to ints

Comment: We need to see the code for function b to help you. Right now it looks like it only accepts integers and you are trying to input a string causing an error.

Comment: @Whud Neither of the functions exist yet. OP expects us to write them for him.

Comment: @hagravens Please show your own attempts.

Comment: Are you saying those ValueError's are what you want, or what you are getting now and you want to avoid them?

Comment: 'they all used things I haven't learned' - is that a problem because this is a homework assignment? otherwise, don't you want to learn something new?

Answer (score 2):

```
def to_tuple(input_number):
    # check if input number is int or not
    if isinstance(input_number,(int)):
        # convert number to string
        to_string = str(input_number)
        # finally convert string to
        # list of numbers followed by converting the list to tuple
        tuple_output = tuple(map(int,to_string))
        return tuple_output
    # if not int return empty tuple
    # well coz nobody likes useful but ugly python tracebacks
    else:
        return ()

# lets see example
number = 3450
print to_tuple(number)
(3, 4, 5, 0)

number = 353984
print to_tuple(number)
(3, 5, 3, 9, 8, 4)

number = 2.6
print to_tuple(number)
()
```

If you like this example I'd post answer for the second part

Comment: thanks for your help. I know it's old and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already state what you can do:
Convert the int to str by doing (I know this does not work for floats, here you can show some further effort:))

```
for c in str(integerVariable):
    print c
```

The other way around is even more simple.

```
''.join(tupleVariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def a(n):
result = []

while n > 0:
    result.append(n%10)
    n=n//10

return tuple(reversed(result))
```

for question 2, try doing the same thing in reverse i.e. multiplying each number by 1, 10, 100 and adding them up.

also don't forget error checking code.